# Clase BufferedReader de java

Tags: java

Resulta que hice un programa donde recibe una Cadena ***String*** o un texto archivo ***txt*** de donde debo sacar las ocurrencias de cada palabra que se encuentra dentro del texto o cadena y tambien sacar las ocurrencias de los signos de puntuacion y signos de interrogacion, exclamacion, y parentesis pero al momento de convertir el texto en una cadena el ***bufferedreder***  no reconce estos signos "¿", "¡" y lo pone en la cadena y cuando lo imprimo me sale esto □ en lugar del signo correspondiente y cuando entro al debugger lo toma como '�' alguna solucion?

Comment: Hay que jugar con el **encoding** para asegurarte que lees el fichero en el formato que corresponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno nada mas me queda decir GRACIAS a los que se interesaron por responder y comentarles que encontre una solucion a mi problema fue **TRABAJAR DIRECTO CON ASCII** 
este es el fragmento de codigo que me resuelve mi problema

```
public String AbrirATexto(File archivo){
            String contenido="";
            try {
                entrada = new FileInputStream(archivo);
                int ascci;
                while((ascci = entrada.read())!= -1){
                    char carcater = (char)ascci;
                    contenido += carcater;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return contenido;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que el problema tenga que ver con el encode fíjate la siguiente línea:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: bueno no me soluciono el problema ahora no me reconoce los caracteres especiales solo las letras

Comment: Hiciste una prueba con "ISO-8859-1" ?, en el caso de que no haya funcionado. Fíjate en que formato grabas el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) de tu archivo y comprueba que se necesita para visualizarlo.

Si usas el constructor `InputStreamReader(InputStream is, String charset)` prueba primero con:

- "ISO-8859-1" (más probable)
- "US-ASCII"
- "UTF-8" (menos probable)

Puedes excluir el `Charset` por defecto en las pruebas, lo obtienes con `InputStreamReader#getEncoding()`.

Alternativamente puedes usar `Charset#availableCharsets()` para obtener un mapa de los `Charset` disponibles para leer el archivo.

Lamentablemente no se puede seguramente determinar la códificación de un archivo de texto, solamente se puede comprobar si hay errores y así determinar que **no** es la códificación sospechada.

Aun, si fuera un archivo en utf-8 que luego se muestra en ISO o ASCII, te saldrían combinaciones de 2 byte en vez de caracteres singulares desconocidos, así lo más probable es que tratas de mostrar un archivo de ISO-8859 en una salida de utf-8.